# Exfat partition created on Ubuntu with important data not visible on Windows?

Tags: partitioning

So I was dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows and wanted to transfer files Ubuntu > Windows. I created an Exfat partition and now it's invisible?? I tried rescan disks and that still didn't work. I had alot of important things on it and now it's not working, please help!

Comment: Is it still vivible in Ubuntu?

Comment: @SorenA yes it is

Comment: This is more a Windows problem then ... are you sure that you re-scanned correctly in windows? And are the partition visible in Windows disk-manager tool? Maybe it's just missing a drive-letter.

Comment: @SorenA Yes im sure, I scanned two times, how do you add a drive letter?

Comment: To set a drive letter, right click start, select Disk Management, right click your exFAT partition, select “Change Drive Letter and Paths”, choose a drive letter....

Comment: @PonJar Everything except "Delete partition" is greyed out

Comment: How much space is used in the exFAT partition? Can you shrink it by 50%, make a new partition in Windows, copy the data using Ubuntu to the new partition and access it from Windows. If this works delete the original partition and expand the new one.

Comment: @PonJar I couldn't shrink it aswell because windows doesn't know it's exfat, but now I deleted the partition and got the 20gb worth of data from my backup